# Como duplicar uma linha na linguagem R

Tags: r

Eu tenho o seguinte dataframe:

> ```
>  Relat_test <- tibble(Raiz_CNPJ = c(1111111,11111111 , 2222222),
>                    Cliente = c('AAAAAAA', 'AAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBB'),
>                    Zona = c('SP', 'SP', 'BA'),
>                    Direcao = c('SPN', 'SPN', 'BAZ'),
>                    Emissao = c('25/08/2023', '25/08/2023', '11/08/2023'),
>                    Vencto =  c('29/09/2023', '29/09/2023', '25/12/2023'),
>                    Total_dir = c(1466277, 1466277, 1738419),
>                    Total_Cliente = c(16000967, 16000967, 17384190),
>                    tipo_garantia = c('FIANCA', 'HIPOTECA', 'FIANCA'),
>                    area_quantidade = c(0, 12, 0),
>                    emissao_contrato = c('02/02/2023','02/02/2023','13/01/2023'),
>                    vencimento = c('02/02/2027','02/02/2027','13/01/2027'),
>                    Valor = c(4000000,1370000,2000000),
>                    garantia_valida = c('S','S','S'),
>                    garantia_formalizada = c('S','S','S'), 
>                    limite = c(3000000,3000000,2000000),
>                    validade = c('31/05/2024','31/05/2024','31/05/2024'))
> ```

O que eu precisaria fazer é:

A primeira e a segunda linha (observação) é do mesmo cliente, porém ele possui a variável "tipo_garantia" diferente. Então precisaria criar uma condição para que a variável "Total_Cliente" diminuísse com a variável "Valor". Se a variável "Total_Cliente" for maior que a variável "Valor", o saldo dela iria para o próximo "tipo_garantia" do mesmo cliente. Se caso o saldo não zerasse, precisaria que criasse uma nova linha do mesmo cliente, alterando a variável "tipo_garantia" para "SEM GARANTIAS" com o valor do saldo restante.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para atingir o resultado desejado, você pode usar a linguagem R e a biblioteca dplyr para manipular o dataframe. A ideia é criar uma lógica que calcula o saldo e cria novas linhas quando necessário. Aqui está um código que faz isso:

```
library(dplyr)

Relat_test <- Relat_test %>%
  arrange(Cliente, Raiz_CNPJ, tipo_garantia) %>%
  group_by(Cliente, Raiz_CNPJ) %>%
  mutate(Saldo = Total_Cliente - cumsum(Valor)) %>%
  mutate(tipo_garantia = if_else(row_number() == n() & Saldo > 0, "SEM GARANTIAS", tipo_garantia)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  bind_rows(Relat_test) %>%
  arrange(Cliente, Raiz_CNPJ)

print(Relat_test)
```

Este código realiza as seguintes operações:

1. Ordena o dataframe por Cliente, Raiz_CNPJ e tipo_garantia.
2. Agrupa os dados pelo Cliente e Raiz_CNPJ.
3. Calcula o Saldo subtraindo o Valor cumulativamente para cada linha.
4. Atualiza a coluna tipo_garantia para "SEM GARANTIAS" quando o Saldo for maior que zero na última linha de cada grupo.
5. Seleciona a primeira linha de cada grupo.
6. Concatena as linhas selecionadas com o dataframe original.
7. Reordena o dataframe novamente.

Isso criará um dataframe onde o Saldo é distribuído corretamente entre as diferentes garantias ou, se necessário, criará uma nova linha com "SEM GARANTIAS" para o saldo restante.

Certifique-se de que sua versão do dplyr esteja atualizada, pois algumas funções podem ter comportamentos diferentes em versões mais antigas.

## Caso em que a soma dos "Valores" seja menor que "Total_Cliente"

Você pode ajustar o código para lidar com o caso em que a soma dos "Valores" seja menor que "Total_Cliente". Nesse caso, você pode criar uma nova linha com "SEM GARANTIAS" e o saldo restante. Aqui está a modificação no código para lidar com esse cenário:

```
library(dplyr)

Relat_test <- Relat_test %>%
  arrange(Cliente, Raiz_CNPJ, tipo_garantia) %>%
  group_by(Cliente, Raiz_CNPJ) %>%
  mutate(Saldo = Total_Cliente - cumsum(Valor)) %>%
  mutate(tipo_garantia = if_else(row_number() == n() & Saldo > 0, "SEM GARANTIAS", tipo_garantia)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  bind_rows(Relat_test) %>%
  arrange(Cliente, Raiz_CNPJ) %>%
  group_by(Cliente, Raiz_CNPJ) %>%
  mutate(Saldo = sum(Saldo)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1 | Saldo > 0) %>%
  mutate(Raiz_CNPJ = if_else(row_number() != 1 & Saldo > 0, NA, Raiz_CNPJ)) %>%
  fill(Raiz_CNPJ) %>%
  mutate(tipo_garantia = if_else(row_number() != 1 & Saldo > 0, "SEM GARANTIAS", tipo_garantia)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Raiz_CNPJ)) %>%
  select(-Saldo)

print(Relat_test)
```

Nesse código, após o primeiro conjunto de operações que você já tinha, adicionamos um novo conjunto de operações que lida com a criação de uma nova linha com "SEM GARANTIAS" e o saldo restante quando a soma dos "Valores" for menor que "Total_Cliente" para o primeiro cliente com vários tipos de garantias. Certificamo-nos de que a linha com "SEM GARANTIAS" seja criada apenas uma vez.

Comment: Primeiro, muito obrigado, excelente o retorno. Só encontrei um probleminha. O primeiro cliente, que possui 2 "tipos_garantias", mesmo somando a variável "Valor", o total dela é menor que a variável "Total_cliente". Teria como trazer para este caso a nova linha com "SEM GARANTIAS"?

Comment: É um prazer @EvertonToledo . Não hesite em aceitar e votar na resposta, isso ajuda-me quando as minhas respostas são rejeitadas. Quanto à sua segunda pergunta, faço-lhe um complemento abaixo

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Acredito que só mais uma questão. O primeiro cliente possui 2 tipos de garantias. o Total_Cliente, gostaria de diminuir o saldo pela garantia, por exemplo: O cliente "AAA" tem de "Total_Cliente" R$ 16000967. o Valor de uma do "tipo_garantia" é  R$ 4000000 e o outro "tipo_garantia" é R$ 1370000, ou seja, o saldo que iria pare este cliente com "tipo_garantia" "SEM GARANTIA" seria Saldo R$ 10630967.

Comment: Peço desculpa, mas estou a ficar sem tempo esta noite e já tenho um downvote @EvertonToledo . Tudo de bom

Comment: tranquilo, muito obrigado pela ajuda, quem dá o downvote? se tu está ajudando muito. Obrigado

Comment: De nada @EvertonToledo . Não hesite em aceitar a pergunta e dar o seu voto positivo, isso ajudar-me-á a evitar ser proibido de responder a perguntas. Não sei quem está a fazer downvoting, acho que não podemos descobrir. Mas a comunidade lusófona aqui é muito elitista e não hesita em dar downvotes.

Comment: Olá @EvertonToledo , se a resposta foi útil para ti, aceita-a e vota, assim não serei banido por ter demasiadas respostas rejeitadas.